# Android - Cursor exception - Index 1 requested with a size of 1

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursor

I have the following code:

```
private Cursor query(String selection, String[] selectionArgs,
        String[] columns, String tableName) {
    /*
     * The SQLiteBuilder provides a map for all possible columns requested
     * to actual columns in the database, creating a simple column alias
     * mechanism by which the ContentProvider does not need to know the real
     * column names
     */
    SQLiteQueryBuilder builder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    builder.setTables(tableName);
    Cursor cursor = builder.query(mDatabase, columns, selection,
            selectionArgs, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) {
        return null;
    } else if (!cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        cursor.close();
        return null;
    }
    return cursor;
}

public List<VEvent> getVEvents(int week, int year) {
    String selection = KEY_WEEK + "=? AND " + KEY_YEAR + "=?";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { String.valueOf(week), String.valueOf(year) };
    Cursor cursor = query(selection, selectionArgs, ALL_CALENDAR_COLUMNS, CALENDAR_TABLE_NAME);
    List<VEvent> events = new ArrayList<VEvent>();
    while (cursor != null) {
        VEvent e = new VEvent();
        try {
        e.getProperties().add(new Uid(cursor.getString(1)));
        e.getProperties().add(new DtStamp(cursor.getString(2)));
        e.getProperties().add(new Organizer(cursor.getString(3)));
        e.getProperties().add(new DtStart(cursor.getString(4)));
        e.getProperties().add(new DtEnd(cursor.getString(5)));
        e.getProperties().add(new Summary(cursor.getString(6)));
        e.getProperties().add(new Location(cursor.getString(7)));
        e.getProperties().add(new Description(cursor.getString(8)));
        events.add(e);
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            Log.v("getvevents", "parse exception : " + ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
            Log.v("getvevents", "uri exception : " + ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    return events;
}
```

When I call getVEvents I receive the following exception:

```
09-08 11:03:10.121: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2696):     android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 requested, with a size of 1
09-08 11:03:10.121: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2696):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:580)
09-08 11:03:10.121: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2696):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:214)
09-08 11:03:10.121: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2696):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:41)
09-08 11:03:10.121: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2696):     at com.unibean.SettingsDatabase.getVEvents(SettingsDatabase.java:177)
```

Line 177 corresponds to

```
e.getProperties().add(new Uid(cursor.getString(1)));
```

In both the query method and getVEvents I'm always checking if the cursor is null, and I am using moveToFirst() and moveToNext(), so I'm not quite sure why the exception is occurring, and what exactly "index 1 requested with a size of 1" actually means.

Many thanks!

Comment: Try moveToFirst() and getString(0).

Answer (score 2):

It means exactly what it says. you're trying to access element 1 (the second since it's zero-based) when the size is only one.

You have a problem with the way you're detecting the end of the data set. Your `cursor` won't magically become `null` after you've processed the last row. Instead, it stays the same value but its internal state changes.

You need to detect the end of the data set in a different way.

You could use, for example:

```
cursor.moveToFirst();
while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
    blah blah blah
    cursor.moveToNext();
}
```

Comment: Do you mean while(!cursor.isAfterLast()) ?

Comment: @Jonny, yes, you must have caught me mid-edit, I'd just noticed that mistake.

Answer (score 1):

The error means that you requested the item with index 1, but the list which your request was sent to only has the size of 1 - meaning it only contains one item and the maximum index therefor is 0.

It would seem that your query only returns a cursor with one row.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
 private Cursor query(String selection, String[] selectionArgs,
            String[] columns, String tableName) {
        /*
         * The SQLiteBuilder provides a map for all possible columns requested
         * to actual columns in the database, creating a simple column alias
         * mechanism by which the ContentProvider does not need to know the real
         * column names
         */
        SQLiteQueryBuilder builder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        builder.setTables(tableName);
        Cursor cursor = builder.query(mDatabase, columns, selection,
                selectionArgs, null, null, null);
        return cursor;
    }

    public List<VEvent> getVEvents(int week, int year) {
        String selection = KEY_WEEK + "=? AND " + KEY_YEAR + "=?";
        String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { String.valueOf(week), String.valueOf(year) };
        Cursor cursor = query(selection, selectionArgs, ALL_CALENDAR_COLUMNS, CALENDAR_TABLE_NAME);
        List<VEvent> events = new ArrayList<VEvent>();
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            VEvent e = new VEvent();
            try {
            e.getProperties().add(new Uid(cursor.getString(1)));
            e.getProperties().add(new DtStamp(cursor.getString(2)));
            e.getProperties().add(new Organizer(cursor.getString(3)));
            e.getProperties().add(new DtStart(cursor.getString(4)));
            e.getProperties().add(new DtEnd(cursor.getString(5)));
            e.getProperties().add(new Summary(cursor.getString(6)));
            e.getProperties().add(new Location(cursor.getString(7)));
            e.getProperties().add(new Description(cursor.getString(8)));
            events.add(e);
            } catch (ParseException ex) {
                Log.v("getvevents", "parse exception : " + ex.getLocalizedMessage());
            } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
                Log.v("getvevents", "uri exception : " + ex.getLocalizedMessage());
            }

        }
        return events;
    }
```